# UITabBar.appearance().tintColor not changing icon colors

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm calling         `UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = Constants.MAIN_COLOR` in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but no matter what I change that color value too, my tab bar icons always appears the color of the actual image when selected. Any idea why my tab bar icons are not changing to the color defined in the code above? I made sure I wasn't calling the UITabBar.appearance() anywhere else in my project as well by doing a search.

Comment: Do you set other tintColors (eg: UIView.appearance().tintColor?)

Comment: No other appearance().tintColor exist in my project.

Comment: Is your tab bar translucent? If so have you tried making it opaque? e.g.

       UITabBar.appearance().translucent = false
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `custom icons`? Then try these methods:

`[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];`

and for text:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{ UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor someColor]}
                                         forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
```